# Apple Remote controlling iPhone

Tags: iphone, appletv, remote-control

I am trying to connect an Apple TV remote to my iPhone so I can test my application with the remote.

But I can not find anything that shows how to connnect the devices together.  Does the remote only connect to the Apple TV?

Answer (score 1):

Support is not just limited to the Apple TV, as the new Siri/touch sensitive remote can also pair with Macs so you can test tvOS apps in Xcode (presumably). Though only some Macs are supported.

However, there's no iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch support (on iOS 9.2 or earlier at least).